# Search kmers of one file in kmers of an other file and count occurences in Python

Tags: python, biopython, fastq

Got this function, which generates all possible kmers over the four Bases in python:

```
def generate_kmers(k):

    bases = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']  # in task (a) we only should wirte a function that generates k-mers of the four Bases
    kmer = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(bases, repeat=length_kmer)]
    # itertools.product returns a Cartesian product of input iterables, in our case it generates over bases and joined
    # all string combinations together over a length of k-mers
    return kmer
```

now what I want is, to look over a list of Sequences of a fastq file (e.g. ['GTATACACTAGTCCAGGATGTGCTTCTTGTAGAAAAGTAAAACAATGGTTAAAAGATCACAATCTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN', 'CCTGTAGAGTCATAAAGACCTCTTGGGTCCATCCTAGAAATTTTTCAGCTGAGAATAACGGGTCTGTTTCAGTTATTGCTTCTACTATNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN']) and count the occurences of all my kmers of the function generate_kmer in my list of Sequences and to save it in a dictionary. (e.g. {AAAA: 2, AAAC: 1...})
First I tried to modify generate_kmer, so that it gives all k-mers of the sequence file, and iterate over kmerSequences and kmerBases but that doesn't worked.

Does somebody has any ideas on how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this with `count`:

```
import itertools

def generate_kmers(k):

    bases = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']  # in task (a) we only should wirte a function that generates k-mers of the four Bases
    kmer = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(bases, repeat=k)]
    # itertools.product returns a Cartesian product of input iterables, in our case it generates over bases and joined
    # all string combinations together over a length of k-mers
    return kmer

seqs=['GTATACACTAGTCCAGGATGTGCTTCTTGTAGAAAAGTAAAACAATGGTTAAAAGATCACAATCTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN', 'CCTGTAGAGTCATAAAGACCTCTTGGGTCCATCCTAGAAATTTTTCAGCTGAGAATAACGGGTCTGTTTCAGTTATTGCTTCTACTATNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN']
k=4
mers4= generate_kmers(k)
dcts=[{kmer:seq.count(kmer) for kmer in mers4}for seq in seqs]
print(dcts)
```

**Edit:**

```
import itertools
import re
def generate_kmers(k):

    bases = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']  # in task (a) we only should wirte a function that generates k-mers of the four Bases
    kmer = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(bases, repeat=k)]
    # itertools.product returns a Cartesian product of input iterables, in our case it generates over bases and joined
    # all string combinations together over a length of k-mers
    return kmer

k=4
mers4= generate_kmers(k)

#given sequence
s='GTATACACTAGTCCAGGATGTGCTTCTTGTAGAAAAGTAAAACAATGGTTAAAAGATCACAATCTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN'

#function that returns the dictionary with ocurrences
def dct_count(seq):
    return {mer:len(re.findall(mer, s)) for mer in mers4}

dc=dct_count(s)
print(dc)
```

Comment: No, I just see 'AAAA' three times in the first sequence and 0 in the second... Could you show me where are the others? Maybe I missunderstud the question

Comment: Nevermind, had a mistake in my mindset, another question:  can I write this in a new function, which generates the dictionary for each Sequence Input I gave him as argument? and your Idea is maybe for a large fastq file inefficient, is there another possibility to count the occurence?

Comment: Yeah, see my edit with the function and with another option to count that using re, but for me, the list and dictionary comprehension could be mostly the best way. And no, I didn't find more options than this two. To make more efficent try to use the function to create the dictionaries. Also, if you found this helpful, you should consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) :).

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot!